# Inequality using integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, partial-differential-equations

Using that

$
u^{2}(x) - u^{2}(0) = \int_{0}^{x}(u^{2}(x))' dx$

and the Cauchy-schwarz inequality, show that if $u(0) = 0$, then exist a constant c such that

$\int_{0}^{b}u^{2}(x)dx < c\int_{0}^{b}(u'(x))^{2}dx $

Someone can give me a hint?

Comment: $u$ is a real function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a solution. Don't read past the first 2 lines if you only want a hint.

We have 
$$\begin{split}
\int_0^b u^2(x)dx &=\int_0^b \left(\int_0^x u^\prime(t) dt\right)^2dx \\
&= \int_0^b \left(\int_0^b 1_{[0, x]}(t)u^\prime(t) dt\right)^2dx\\
&\leq \int_0^b \left(\sqrt {\int_0^b (1_{[0, x]}(t))^2dt}\sqrt {\int_0^b (u^\prime(t))^2dt} \right)^2dx \mbox{ by CS}\\
&\leq \int_0^bb\int_0^b (u^\prime(t))^2dt dx\\
&\leq b^2 \int_0^b (u^\prime(t))^2dt
\end{split}$$

Comment: how can you say $\int_{0}^{b}(1_{[0, x]}(t))^{2}dt = b$

Comment: I'm saying the integral on the left is less than or equal to $b$.